# HL7 validator in pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I want to know if there is a solution in pentaho kettle to validate a message hl7 before parsing, I want some thing like exposed here 
http://try-it.caristix.com:9030/default.aspx 
but in a step pentaho kettle or a hole transformation which do the same.

Comment: I know nothing about HL7. Are these "messages" in separate files, or do they come from a web service or service bus or something like that? I think you'll need an external validator for the messages, but the question would be how to call that validator. That depends on how the messages are stored.

Comment: yes, i receive messages from a web service, but i want a validator inside the transformtaion.

Comment: Then I would guess you'd need a Java validator that you could load as a jar file and then call it from a `Modified Javascript Value` step. Unfortunately, I know nothing about HL7 validators.

Comment: can i use code java in modified javascript value step ??? i think you want to mention java step !?

Comment: Yes, you can use any regular java class in the `Modified Javascript Value` step because the default Javascript interpreter is Rhino. I'm afraid I no longer have access to an example, but there are good web resources on how to use Java classes from Rhino.

Comment: There is a step called data validator. Try using it.